# Visual Studio 2013 Indent buttons are grayed out (not working) after importing settings from VS 2012

Tags: button, import, settings, indentation, visual-studio-2013

Ok, it's goodda be something simple.

Installed VS 2013 > imported settings from VS 2012 > Decrease/Increase buttons are grayed out (not clickable).

If I reset settings to stock they work fine again.

I have set **Text Editor > All Languages > Tabs** to **Block** and **Insert Spaces**. I tried different combinations, but still doesn't work.

There is has to be some small setting somewhere that I missed that enables/disables them.

Thanks!!!

Comment: This fixed it for me.. Text Editor > All Languages > Tabs to Block and Insert Spaces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it! Really simple!

I have had 'Selection Uninednt' and 'Selection Indent' buttons added, while I should have had 'Line Unindent' and 'Line Indent':
[image]

Comment: Very nice answer! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had to turn off smart indent in
Tools >> Options :: Text Editor / All Languages / Tabs

Comment: I tried every command that had "indent" and "outdent" and none worked. Turning off smart indent did the trick. thanks!

Comment: I don't worry about those buttons anymore, because now, I just use select lines and tab (or shift-tab) to indent (or unindent) text.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Tools -->Customize
2. Check Text Editor and close

A grayed tool bar will appear.

3. Now click on Text Editor Toolbar Option dropdown -->Add or Remove Buttons --> Check Decrease Line Indent & Increase Line Indent and you are done. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for me it worked the other way around...

As for the option of:

*Tools >> Options :: Text Editor / All Languages / Tabs*

I DIDN'T have this option checked and once I checked it (along with enabling *Smart Tabs*), the shortcut for indenting (*Tab*) and unindenting (*Shift + Tab*) **selected** lines started to work perfectly.